# how to set metadata in flowplayer

Tags: jquery, flash, actionscript, flowplayer

I have the scaling set to "fit" because it scales the video up or down preserving its aspect ratio but the metadata has the wrong width for the video so that means scaling preserves the wrong aspect ratio. I have a video that should be 853x480 but in flowplayer it is 720x480. I know you can get the metadata width by writing this

```
onMetaData: function(clip){ 
  alert(clip.metaData.width);
},
```

but how do you set it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the metadata using flowplayer because it is the data that is stored in the FLV file. You will need to use a metadata injector.

see http://osflash.org/flv#metadata for more info

If you want to change the apsect ratio on the fly you should use `scale` for the scaling value and set the correct height and width of the div being used by flowplayer.

Comment: yeah that would work for me but then I lose the aspect ratio in fullscreen.

Comment: setting scale as the scaling value and setting the correct height and width of the div being used by flowplayer solves half of my problem how can I force the 16:9 aspect ratio on fullscreen.